# JavaScript If Else events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following script which functions perfectly:

```
function showResult(questionId) {
  if(answers[questionId] == useranswers[questionId]) {
    document.getElementById('result_' + questionId).innerHTML = '<img src="correct.gif" style="border:0" alt="Correct!" />';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('result_' + questionId).innerHTML = '<img src="incorrect.gif" style="border:0" alt="Incorrect!" />';
  }
}
```

I would like the ELSE condition to perform a second action- show the correct answer when the user has chosen the wrong answer, e.g. like making the correct answer appear in Green. This is for a multiple choice question that has four choices with only one correct answer.

All help appreciated.

Comment: So put a nested if statement in there?

Answer (score 0):

```
function name(){
  if(this == that){
    then;
  }else if(this2 == that2){
    then2;
  }
}
```

You can always nest IF statements or you can duplicate ELSE IF calls like above to infinity...

Comment: Thanks for Speedy reply ANDEHLU, but I have mínimum idea of JavaScript.